# Highly periodical time series datasets?

Tags: data-request, time-series, seasonality

I'm looking for a highly periodical time series dataset. Mainly, this is what I am looking for:

- Periodic time series. No preference over the frequency, it can be annual, monthly or even daily.
- The time series can be fine even in case it is periodical in some parts of it but not periodical in general
- At least 100 observations would be nice
- The dataset should be free to use to everyone and publicly available.

Comment: Could you please provide more details, to help us answer: I am not sure of what you mean by "highly periodical" wrt "even in case it is periodical in some parts of it but not periodical in general"? What is the purpose, in a few words?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seasonal Sales Data for time Series Analysis](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10313/3987) (I don't have enough rep here to VTC as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 2):

If you need something *purely* periodic, consider using sunrise/sunset for a given latitude/longitude.

There are simple scripts available to generate as much data as you need. See this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19617490/2327328) for some python and java options. Python implementations oftenuse the [Ephem](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyephem/) package.

They also mention using a web-service, [sunrise-sunset.org](http://api.sunrise-sunset.org).

Answer (score 1):

In Germany water levels are published by the German "Wasserstraßen und Schifffahrtsverwaltung" which is part of the Federal Ministry of Transport and Digital Infrastructure.

They offer REST-APIs [free of charge and for inclusion in apps](https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/gast/nutzungsbedingungen).

Check for example water levels for [Helgoland (in the North Sea)](https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/gast/stammdaten?pegelnr=9510075#detail?id=0d8233b8-36c9-4a24-ad77-a4e7c617932f)

JSON:
[https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/HELGOLAND%20SÜDHAFEN/W/measurements.json?start=P15D](https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/HELGOLAND%20S%C3%9CDHAFEN/W/measurements.json?start=P15D)

API Documentation is [here](https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservice/guideRestapi) (in German).

There will be offerings from similar organisations in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo finance > Historical Data

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL

Example:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1493539980&period2=1496131980&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=YPa1GnhtzrJ