# Worldwide sunrise and sunset time data

Tags: data-request, api, weather

Looking for a database or free API with the expected sunrise and sunset times around the world (sunrise is more important). Ideally the data should be up-to-date, reflecting daily changes in weather in any given area.

Good example would be [http://www.weatherbase.com](http://www.weatherbase.com/weather/weather.php3?s=58301&cityname=Berlin-Berlin-Germany#), but their API has to be licensed.

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488 may or may not be helpful. "Expected" sunrise/sunset times don't depend on the weather-- real ones might, but only slightly. As the linked post notes, you can actually compute expected sunrise and sunset or your own.

Comment: This answer may be useful https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11284/1511 - but yes, you can easy calculate yourself based on lat/long

Comment: @philshem Yes, it is a very useful answer to my question. Indeed weather patterns do not have influence on this.

Comment: Okay, give me some time to get familiar with the available options